# How to change background color using :after selector by jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I change the background color of the popup letter using jQuery?

```css
.map-button a.active:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-button">
  <a href="#" data-id="0900" title="A">
    <span class="sr-only">A</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Under what event?

Comment: all I'm seeing is css and html, where's your jquery attempt?

Comment: You can't select pseudo-elements using jQuery. If you want to alter the style of a pseudo-element, give the element a class instead.